# redux-form getFormState side-effects

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have many forms in my app. I created a single form reducer for each of them under its parent reducer and combined them. For fetching theirs data I am using `getFormState`, Everything is okay in fetching form states side, but in redux state active form duplicated in all redux-form reducers!!!
Each redux-form action apply to all forms.

[image: redux-form in redux-dev-tools screenshot]

I don't know how I can share all code with you that I can present whole situation. but I try share some code btw here:

This is my signup form:

```
SigninForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'signin',
  validate,
  getFormState: ({ auth }) => auth.signin.form
})(SigninForm)
```

sign up reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form'

const signin = combineReducers({
  error,
  isLogging,
  form: reduxFormReducer
})

export default signin
```

and Filters form:

```
export default compose(
  connect(null, { ...actions }),
  reduxForm({
    form: 'filters',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    initialValues: {
      pool: 'either',
      open_house: false,
      listing_statuses: {
        ...activeStatuses
      },
      property_subtypes,
      minimum_sold_date: '3', // unit is month but it need to timestamp
      minimum_bedrooms: 'any',
      minimum_bathrooms: 'any',
      minimum_parking_spaces: 'any'
    },
    getFormState: ({ search }) => search.filters.form
  }),
  withHandlers({
    onSubmitHandler: ({ submitFiltersForm }) => values => {
      submitFiltersForm(values)
    }
  })
)(Filters)
```

and my root reducer:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  socket,
  user,
  auth,
  brand,
  search,
  routing: routerReducer,
  listing: createNamedWrapperReducer(listing, 'LISTING')
})

export default (state, action) => appReducer(state, action)
```

P.S: when I use a single form reducer in my root reducer without use `getFormState` everything working well.

`OS: Mac,
    node: 8.3.0,
    react: 15.4.2,
    redux: 3.6.0,
    redux-form: 7.0.0,
    browser: 60.0.3112.101 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: Please share the code related code

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a Redux issue than anything else.

See, in Redux, *all* reducers receive *all* actions.
This is an architectural decision that makes it simple to react to weird business ideas.

Therefore, if you're duplicating the redux-form reducer all around your codebase, you're also duplicating the state of *all* forms, since the actions type is the same for *every* form.

The `getFormState` option is not meant to work around multiple instances of the reducer; it's meant to place your redux-form state somewhere else, in case the root-level `form` key cannot be used.

Therefore, the solution is to do what you say in the question, and use a single form reducer in your entire application.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you do not use redux-form properly (correct me if I'm wrong).

From [getting started](https://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/GettingStarted.md/#step-1-of-4-form-reducer):

> **Form Reducer**
>
> It serves for all of your form components, so you only have to pass it
>   once.

Redux-form assumes that there's **only one redux-form reducer in your entire application's state**. In other words, form reducer shall not be nested.

Remove this

```
const signin = combineReducers({
  error,
  isLogging,
  form: reduxFormReducer // <-- delete this line
})
```

and append this

```
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from 'redux-form'
...
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  socket,
  user,
  auth,
  brand,
  search,
  routing: routerReducer,
  listing: createNamedWrapperReducer(listing, 'LISTING'),
  form: reduxFormReducer // <-- that's all there is to it
})

export default (state, action) => appReducer(state, action)
```

then in your component

```
SigninForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'signin',
  validate,
  getFormState: ({ form }) => form // <-- you don't need to use this line now
})(SigninForm)
```

From [docs](http://redux-form.com/7.0.3/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/):

> **getFormState : Function [optional]**
>
> A function that takes the entire Redux state and returns the state
>   slice which corresponds to where the redux-form reducer was mounted.
>   This functionality is rarely needed, and defaults to assuming that the
>   reducer is mounted under the form key.

Since we've mounted the formReducer under the form key, no need to have `getFormState` there at all.

Comment: @patrik-prevuznk I know this and I explained in my question that I don't have any issue when I am adding a reduxform reducer in my root reducer under form property or whatever.. I have problem with nested reducer when I define redux-form under other top reducers like search and auth.

Comment: @Naser, I think the problem comes from getFormState: It's meant to fetch data

Comment: So, why do you need to nest form under other top reducers ?

Comment: Thanks, I did not notice in the docs that there should be one form reducer for the enitre app, it helped me simplify my reducers.